# Fluent approach and org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Compound class names not permitted

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use the fluent approach, but can't resolve my problem with this error:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Compound class names not
> permitted

When I use the normal way there is no any error. I also tried xpath, linktext, partiallinktext and I still getting the same problem.

```
public class HomePage {

@FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='Create an Account']")
private WebElement createAccountLink;

private WebDriver driver;

public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    this.driver = driver;
}

public CreateAccountPage openCreateAccountPage() {
    createAccountLink.click();
    return new CreateAccountPage(driver);
}
}

public class CreateAccountPage {

@FindBy(id = "firstname")
private WebElement regFirstNameInput;

@FindBy(id = "lastname")
private WebElement regLastNameInput;

@FindBy(id = "email_address")
private WebElement regEmailInput;

@FindBy(id = "password")
private WebElement regPasswordInput;

@FindBy(id = "password_confirmation")
private WebElement regPasswordConfirmationInput;

@FindBy(className = "action submit primary")
private WebElement createAccountButton;

private WebDriver driver;

public CreateAccountPage(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    this.driver = driver;
}

public LoggedUserPage registerUserValidData(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
    registerUser(firstName, lastName, email, password);
    return new LoggedUserPage(driver);
}

private void registerUser(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
    regFirstNameInput.sendKeys(firstName);
    regLastNameInput.sendKeys(lastName);
    regEmailInput.sendKeys(email);
    regPasswordInput.sendKeys(password);
    regPasswordConfirmationInput.sendKeys(password);
    createAccountButton.click();
}
}

public class RegisterTest extends BaseTest {

@Test
public void registerUserTest() {
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);

    WebElement dashboardLink = new HomePage(driver)
            .openMyAccountPage()
            .registerUserValidData("test" + random + "30@test.pl", "test@test.pl")
            .getDashboardLink();

    Assert.assertEquals(dashboardLink.getText(), "Dashboard");
}
```

Comment: You aren't getting the `Compound class names not permitted` message when using "xpath, linktext, partiallinktext". Clarity in your question would help. Also, the code you've posted doesn't really clarify the problem... you've posted too much code. All you needed to post was the code related to the element you were having a problem with.

Answer (score 1):

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Compound class names not permitted

This is a very specific error message for a very specific issue. You are passing more than one class name to the `@FindBy(className = "action submit primary")` locator.

With the sample HTML

```
<div class="action submit primary">test</div>
```

in your code you are using

```
@FindBy(className = "action submit primary")
private WebElement createAccountButton;
```

and that's why you are getting that error message. "action", "submit", and "primary" are three separate classes. You might be able to use just one class name but if you need all three classes to uniquely identify the element, you'll need to switch to a CSS selector,

```
@FindBy(css = ".action.submit.primary")
```

Comment: Wow, it works! I didn't expect an error in this line. Thank you so much.